# Example of a sequence having convergent subsequence

Tags: general-topology

We have that in a compact set, every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Can someone please give a counterexample when we drop closedness?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean when we consider non-compact sets? or are you working in spaces where compact = closed and bounded?

Comment: @Ben yes thats what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X = (0,1)$ is not closed.  The sequence $1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots$ has no subsequence that converges to a limit **in $X$**.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X=(0,1)$ and $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ge 2$. That sequence does not converge in $X$ and also you can prove that it has no convergent subsequences.

Comment: I think you should adjust the definition of $a_n$ just slightly. Either that, or adjust the definition of $X$ just slightly.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks, I forgot about $n=1$